# Windows console degrades: programs suddenly not able to handle ctrl-c

Tags: windows-7, console

Once in a while console programs that I run are unable to handle <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>. The examples are `cygwin` programs, if I run them in the console instead of `mintty` and the command line audio tool `sox.exe`.

I usually type <kbd>Win-R</kbd>, `cmd`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then start a program.

Normally, when you run a Cygwin `bash` shell in a Windows console and press ctrl-c, it handles it and re-prints its prompt, but now it's terminated and I'm prompted `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`

Normally, `sox.exe` prints an "aborted" message in response to ctrl-c, but now it crashes and the standard `sox.exe has stopped working` GUI popup is displayed.

Besides, if I start some programs from a `.bat` file, I also get another popup: `windows command processor has stopped working`

After reboot it all works again. Logoff/login or Switch user don't work.

The following simple program also crashes on my machine, but the same binary succeeds on another one:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

static BOOL WINAPI MyHandlerRoutine(
    _In_ DWORD dwCtrlType
) {
    switch (dwCtrlType) {
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        printf("ctrl-c pressed\n");
        return TRUE;
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        printf("ctrl-break pressed\n");
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    DWORD dw = 0;
    BOOL b;

    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    b = GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &dw);
    printf("GetConsoleMode() returned %d %u\n", (int)b, dw);

    dw = dw & ~(ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);

    dw = ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT;

    SetLastError(0);

    b = SetConsoleMode(hStdin, dw);
    printf("SetConsoleMode(%u) returned %d\n", dw, (int)b);

    if (!b) {
        printf("GetLastError() returned %u\n", GetLastError());
    }

    b = SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyHandlerRoutine, TRUE);
    printf("SetConsoleCtrlHandler() returned %d\n", (int)b);

    printf("press ENTER to exit\n");
    for (;;) {
        char buf[1];
        c = getchar();
        printf("%02x ", c);
        // EOF == c || 
        if (10 == c || 13 == c) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you starting your console programs? Are you launching them from a shortcut, or from a batch file, or are you opening a Command Prompt then manually launching the executable?

Comment: I usually type Win-R, cmd, Enter and then start a program.

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your response into your question